# R - Apply function - Replacing Observations with 0 Depending on an Observation's Variable to Determine which column to Start

Tags: r, apply

I have the following data frame:

```
Farm <- c("ABC","DEF","XYZ")
YearlyVolume <- c(500, 1000, 200)
Forecast.2017.03.31 <- c(100, 200, 40)
Forecast.2017.06.30 <- c(150, 300, 40)
Forecast.2017.09.30 <- c(100, 100, 60)
Forecast.2017.12.31 <- c(150, 500, 100)
Disable <- c(NA,TRUE,TRUE)
Start <- c(NA,"2017.06.30",NA)

df <- data.frame(Farm, YearlyVolume, Forecast.2017.03.31, Forecast.2017.06.30, Forecast.2017.09.30, Forecast.2017.12.31, Disable, Start)

Sequence <- c("2017.03.31","2017.06.30", "2017.09.30", "2017.12.31")
```

If the "Disable" variable is TRUE I want to replace all the forecasts for the observation with 0, unless the "Start" variable indicates the date in which to start deleting the variables. So that I get the following table:

```
Farm <- c("ABC","DEF","XYZ")
YearlyVolume <- c(500, 1000, 200)
Forecast.2017.03.31 <- c(100, 200, 0)
Forecast.2017.06.30 <- c(150, 0, 0)
Forecast.2017.09.30 <- c(100, 0, 0)
Forecast.2017.12.31 <- c(150, 0, 0)
Disable <- c(NA,TRUE,TRUE)
Start <- c(NA,"2017.06.30",NA) 

df2 <- data.frame(Farm, YearlyVolume, Forecast.2017.03.31, Forecast.2017.06.30, Forecast.2017.09.30, Forecast.2017.12.31, Disable, Start)
```

I am using the following formula to be able to replace all forecast indicated as "TRUE". However it does not take into consideration the date in which to start replacing forecast with 0.

```
df[,grep(paste0("Forecast.",min(Sequence)),colnames(df)):grep(paste0("Forecast.",max(Sequence)),colnames(df))] <- apply(df[,grep(paste0("Forecast.",min(Sequence)),colnames(df)):grep(paste0("Forecast",max(Sequence)),colnames(df))], 2, 
    function(x) { replace(x,df$Disable == TRUE,0)})
```

In order to take into consideration Start date, I tried to replace the min(sequence) portion with ifelse(!is.na(df$Start),df$Start,min(sequence)) such that it looks like the following:

```
df[,grep(paste0("Forecast.",ifelse(!is.na(df$Start),df$Start,min(sequence))),colnames(df)):grep(paste0("Forecast.",max(Sequence)),colnames(df))] <- apply(df[,grep(paste0("Forecast.",ifelse(!is.na(df$Start),df$Start,min(sequence))),colnames(df)):grep(paste0("Forecast",max(Sequence)),colnames(df))], 2, 
    function(x) { replace(x,df$Disable == TRUE,0)})
```

however I get the following error:

> "argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Not sure how I should change the code in order to reference the Start "date" when it exists.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would restructure the date to a long format: Farm YearlyVolume Date Forecast Disable Start. Then the transformation will be much easier, since you have two date columns to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. We create a function that replaces the values with 0, i.e.

```
Fun1 <- function(df, var, n) {
  ind1 <- grep('Forecast.', names(df))
  replace(df[n,], var[n]:max(ind1), 0)
  }


#create a new column which indicates when to start replacing with 0 based on Start variable
df$new <- sapply(df$Start, function(i) match(i, sub('^Forecast.', '', names(df))))

#Handle the NA in column "new"
df$new[is.na(df$new) & df$Disable == TRUE] <- min(ind1)

#Identify rows to change the values
ind2 <- which(!is.na(df$new))

#Apply the function
df[ind2,] <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(ind2, function(i) unlist(Fun1(df, df$new, i)))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#use ind1 to convert to integers,
df[ind1] <- lapply(df[ind1], as.integer)


#Farm YearlyVolume Forecast.2017.03.31 Forecast.2017.06.30 Forecast.2017.09.30 Forecast.2017.12.31 Disable      Start  new
#1  ABC          500                 100                 150                 100                 150    <NA>       <NA> <NA>
#2  DEF         1000                 200                   0                   0                   0    TRUE 2017.06.30    4
#3  XYZ          200                   0                   0                   0                   0    TRUE       <NA>    3
```

**NOTE**

I read your data frame with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, i.e.

```
df <- data.frame(Farm, YearlyVolume, 
                  Forecast.2017.03.31, Forecast.2017.06.30, Forecast.2017.09.30, 
                  Forecast.2017.12.31, Disable, Start, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution and is exactly what I am looking for. However, when trying to implement it, the portion of the code where I apply the function causes the all the variables for the row we are trying to replace with 0's to be replaced with all 1's. My source data frame has other variables of differing variable types, I had tried applying stringsAsFactors however it will replace the entire observation with 1's

Comment: Then I suggest you share a `dput` sample of your actual data since what you provided does not account for everything

Comment: I was able to get this to work by applying the function after subsetting the required variables only.